# How to adjust text color for Horizontal Line Annotation for Syncfusion chart?

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I'm implementing some HorizontalLineAnnotation elements on my Syncfusion chart, and it's working fine. However, I can't find just the properties for the Annotation that control the Text Size and Color, as well as those for the annotation's label.

These all seem to render blue in default and I'm not getting any options in either XAML or C# to change these properties. I see those properties available for other types of annotations, but none for the HorizontalLineAnnotation. Any help on what I'm missing?

Thanks.

XAML CODE:

```
<chart:HorizontalLineAnnotation Y1="48.92" ShowAxisLabel="True" Text="Yesterday's Close" StrokeColor="yellow" FillColor="red" />
```

C# CODE

```
 HorizontalLineAnnotation horizontalLineAnnotation = new HorizontalLineAnnotation()
  {
  Y1 = 49.92,
  ShowAxisLabel = true,
  Text = "Today's Open"
 };
 chart.ChartAnnotations.Add(horizontalLineAnnotation);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the Syncfusion [samples](https://github.com/syncfusion/xamarin-demos), you'll find [this](https://github.com/syncfusion/xamarin-demos/blob/f8e416c266e00c56327020c35471951c07062eb8/Forms/Chart/Chart/Samples/Annotations/Annotations.xaml.cs#L38)

```
ChartAnnotationLabelStyle horizontalAnnotationLabelStyle = new ChartAnnotationLabelStyle();
horizontalAnnotationLabelStyle.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20);
horizontalAnnotationLabelStyle.VerticalTextAlignment = ChartAnnotationAlignment.Start;
horizontalAnnotationLabelStyle.HorizontalTextAlignment = ChartAnnotationAlignment.End;
horizontalLineAnnotation.LabelStyle = horizontalAnnotationLabelStyle;
```

and according to the [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms~Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.ChartAnnotationLabelStyle_members.html), there are properties for TextColor, BackgroundColor, etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Using the information you provided, I used the following code and was able to accomplish my goal.

```
HorizontalLineAnnotation horizontalLineAnnotation = new HorizontalLineAnnotation()
 {
  Y1 = (double)quoteData.previousClose,
  ShowAxisLabel = true,
  Text = "Yesterday's Close",
  StrokeColor = Color.FromHex("#55daec0e"),
 };

horizontalLineAnnotation.LabelStyle.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#55daec0e");
myChart.ChartAnnotations.Add(horizontalLineAnnotation);
```